# Plugin '0' is not loaded error even on a brand new server

Tags: mysql

I've got this plugin error without changing anything on my server.. I couldn't fix it after many different tries I found on internet so I decided to use mysql on docker.. but...I am getting this error even installing a brand new mysql server via docker.

here is the log of a brand new docker MySQL mysql:5.7.22

```
2022-01-16T12:18:20.967474Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2022-01-16T12:18:20.973049Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2022-01-16T12:18:20.973731Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2022-01-16T12:18:20.973748Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'magento@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2022-01-16T12:18:20.973754Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'akeneo@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2022-01-16T12:18:20.973764Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'magento magento@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2022-01-16T12:18:20.973767Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'akeneo akeneo@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2022-01-16T12:18:20.973774Z 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2022-01-16T12:18:20.973777Z 0 [Warning] The plugin '0' used to authenticate user 'root'@'localhost' is not loaded. Nobody can currently login using this account.
2022-01-16T12:18:20.973778Z 0 [Warning] The plugin '0' used to authenticate user 'magento'@'localhost' is not loaded. Nobody can currently login using this account.
2022-01-16T12:18:20.973780Z 0 [Warning] The plugin '0' used to authenticate user 'akeneo'@'localhost' is not loaded. Nobody can currently login using this account.
2022-01-16T12:18:20.973782Z 0 [Warning] The plugin '0' used to authenticate user 'magento'@'%' is not loaded. Nobody can currently login using this account.
2022-01-16T12:18:20.973783Z 0 [Warning] The plugin '0' used to authenticate user 'akeneo'@'%' is not loaded. Nobody can currently login using this account.
2022-01-16T12:18:20.974111Z 0 [Warning] System table 'time_zone_leap_second' is expected to be transactional.
2022-01-16T12:18:20.974116Z 0 [Warning] System table 'time_zone_name' is expected to be transactional.
2022-01-16T12:18:20.974117Z 0 [Warning] System table 'time_zone' is expected to be transactional.
2022-01-16T12:18:20.974119Z 0 [Warning] System table 'time_zone_transition_type' is expected to be transactional.
2022-01-16T12:18:20.974120Z 0 [Warning] System table 'time_zone_transition' is expected to be transactional.
2022-01-16T12:18:20.974450Z 0 [Warning] System table 'servers' is expected to be transactional.
2022-01-16T12:18:20.976506Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 220116 12:18:20
2022-01-16T12:18:20.977635Z 0 [ERROR] Column count of mysql.db is wrong. Expected 22, found 23. The table is probably corrupted
2022-01-16T12:18:20.977645Z 0 [ERROR] mysql.user has no `Event_priv` column at position 28
2022-01-16T12:18:20.977746Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.event: expected column 'sql_mode' at position 14 to have type set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','NOT_USED','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES','STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','STRICT_ALL_TABLES','NO_ZERO_IN_DATE','NO_ZERO_DATE','INVALID_DATES','ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO','TRADITIONAL','NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER','HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE','NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION','PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH'), found type set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','IGNORE_BAD_TABLE_OPTIONS','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES','STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','STRICT_A
2022-01-16T12:18:20.977752Z 0 [ERROR] Event Scheduler: An error occurred when initializing system tables. Disabling the Event Scheduler.
2022-01-16T12:18:20.977887Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.22'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

I am lost. is it my server that may have a bigger issue?

Comment: Have you checked https://serverfault.com/questions/761001/mysql-authentification-plugin-is-not-loaded ?

Comment: I suggest looking on [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20160221002152/http://kb.odin.com/en/126676) ,too

Comment: 5.7.22 is quite old have you thought about upgrading it to 36

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this option @Ergest too. here is the example:

```
version: '2'

services:

  mysql:
    image: 'mysql:5.7.22'
    ports:
            - "33306:3306"
    volumes:
            - /root/backups/Backup_Akeneo/09-01-2022/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
      MYSQL_USER: 'akeneo_pim'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'akeneo_pim'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'akeneo_pim'
    networks:
      - 'akeneo'
```

I check if that is running:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                NAMES
4a45a3c9d665        mysql:5.7.22           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds        0.0.0.0:33306->3306/tcp              akeneo_mysql_1
```

then I run the upgrade

```
        root@Ubuntu-1910-eoan-64-minimal /var/www/html/akeneo # docker exec -it 4a45a3c9d665 bash
        root@4a45a3c9d665:/# mysql_upgrade -u root -p
        Enter password:
        Checking if update is needed.
        Checking server version.
        Running queries to upgrade MySQL server.
    Checking system database.
    mysql.columns_priv                                 OK
    mysql.db                                           OK
.....
akeneo.pim_versioning_version                      OK
sys.sys_config                                     OK
Upgrade process completed successfully.
Checking if update is needed.
```

Then I try to connect

```
root@4a45a3c9d665:/# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin '0' is not loaded
```